# mkbundle produces non-functional console exe

Tags: windows, mono, mkbundle

I can successfully build a bundled exe from my MonoDevelop C# project, but when I run the bundle, it doesn't do anything; execution is terminated immediately and silently.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Mono 2.10.5 on 64-bit Windows 7 with cygwin generally following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321207/how-to-convert-a-simple-net-console-project-a-into-portable-exe-with-mono-and-mk), but with [these modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308044/mkbundle-and-gtk).  The exact steps I follow are:

1. Create new C# console project in MonoDevelop (contains only `Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");`)
2. Change target to Release
3. Build all
4. In cygwin: `mkbundle -c -o host.c -oo bundle.o --deps BundleTest.exe`
5. Edit host.c, add `#undef _WIN32` after `#endif` after `#include <windows.h>`
6. In cygwin: `gcc -mno-cygwin -o test.exe -Wall host.c 'pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2|dos2unix' bundle.o`
7. In command prompt: `test.exe`
8. In command prompt: `BundleTest.exe`

In step 7, the text "Hello World!" is printed in the command prompt as expected.  In step 8, nothing is printed in the command prompt; the exact same response can be elicited by typing rem and pressing enter.

EDIT: Someone else edited this question to switch steps 7 and 8, which substantively changes the description of the observed behavior.  I don't know why they felt justified in doing this since they were not the ones making the observations, but it is so far removed from the time I was thinking about this problem that I don't want to just switch the back the way they were.  So, note that the last paragraph before this edit probably doesn't accurately reflect my original observations any more.

Answer (score 3):

For building console application you should remove -mwindows flags from /lib/pkgconfig/mono-2.pc