# How to make "mkbundle --deps" option working with mono 3.2.3

Tags: c#, mono, mkbundle

I am trying to bundle the application with mono 3.2.3 to a stand-alone executable. To do so, I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21726468/2139804) guideline. After declarating variables:

```
mono_version="3.2.3"
export MONO=/cygdrive/c/progra~2/Mono-$mono_version
machineconfig=$PROGRAMFILES\\Mono-$mono_version\\etc\\mono\\4.5\\machine.config
export PATH=$PATH:$MONO/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$MONO/lib/pkgconfig
export CC="i686-pc-mingw32-gcc -U _WIN32"
```

mkbundle --deps command cannot localize referenced assemblies:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp' or 
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'gtk-sharp'
```

performing exactly the same operation with mono 2.10.9:

```
mono_version="2.10.9"
export MONO=/cygdrive/c/progra~2/Mono-$mono_version
machineconfig=$PROGRAMFILES\\Mono-$mono_version\\etc\\mono\\4.0\\machine.config
export PATH=$PATH:$MONO/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$MONO/lib/pkgconfig
export CC="i686-pc-mingw32-gcc -U _WIN32"

mkbundle --deps --machine-config "$machineconfig" -c UI.exe
```

gives positive result:

```
OS is: Windows
WARNING:
  Check that the machine.config file you are bundling
  doesn't contain sensitive information specific to this machine.
Sources: 3 Auto-dependencies: True
   embedding: C:\users\piotr\desktop\authoringtool\UI\bin\debug\UI.exe
 config from: C:\users\piotr\desktop\authoringtool\UI\bin\debug\UI.exe.config
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.9\lib\mono\gac\gtk-sharp\2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\gtk-sharp.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.9\lib\mono\gac\glib-sharp\2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\glib-sharp.dll
   .
   .
   .
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.9\lib\mono\4.0\Mono.Posix.dll
Machine config from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.9\etc\mono\4.0\machine.config
Compiling:
as -o temp.o temp.s
```

Does anyone know the reason of such behavior? I'm using 64-bit version of windows 7 and the Cygwin I found on the official website. The code was compiled and tested on Xamarin Studio 4.2 and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Having the same problem, hopefully this will get some more attention

Comment: Can you check if this thread is helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308044/mkbundle-and-gtk

Comment: Unfortunately not. From September 2013 MinGW compiler is not supported by Cygwin anymore (-gcc-mingw package was removed). That is also the reason why so many people have so many problems with mkbundle right now

Answer (score 1):

## Howto for mkbundle on cygwin + mingw

*Tested with mono 4.0.3*
**In mono 4.0.3, mkbundle works but it can be tricky to make it work.**

First, check your setup:

- Install Mono/GTK# in a **path that doesn't contains spaces** (ie not Program Files then)
- Setup a **MinGw/Cygwin** working compile chain (as [the one for
  compiling mono on windows](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/windows/)).
- Define the mandatory **environment variables** for mkbundle:

  - mingw compiler location should be in the Windows PATH (used by cmd)
  - pkg-config should also be in the Windows PATH
- Use the following cygwin script (it can be adapted to run on cmd)

> ```
> # M_PREFIX refers to Mono installation
> # For more information, search for prefix installation in Mono documentation
> M_PREFIX='/cygdrive/c/Mono'
>
> export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=${M_PREFIX}/lib:${DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH}
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${M_PREFIX}/lib:${M_PREFIX}/lib/mono/4.5:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
> export C_INCLUDE_PATH=${M_PREFIX}/include:${C_INCLUDE_PATH}
> export ACLOCAL_PATH=${M_PREFIX}/share/aclocal:${ACLOCAL_PATH}
> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${M_PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}
> # Here we added the system32 to make cmd available to mkbundle
> # /usr/bin is the default location for mingw
> export PATH=${M_PREFIX}/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/usr/bin:${PATH}
>
> export CC="i686-pc-mingw32-gcc -U _WIN32"
> ```

Then you can run:

```
mkbundle --deps --keeptemp my.exe my.dll -o bundled.exe
```

**Notes:**
 - **Copy `mono-2.0.dll` in the application directory as it should be distributed along the bundled exe**

```
cp ${M_PREFIX}/bin/mono-2.0.dll .
```

- if **`-z`** is used, zlib1.dll should be copied as well. (note that gcc invocation change also). You may need more dll depending on your usage of framework features (not exhaustive list : libglib*.dll, libgmodule*.dll, libgthread*.dll, iconv.dll, intl.dll)
- **`-c`** is used to generate only stub.
- You must specify **all exe and dll** that are needed for the bundle.
- **`--keeptemp`** will keep temp.c and temp.s which could come in handy if mkbundle fail on gcc invocation.
- If you want to invoke gcc by hand (and it may be needed):

```
i686-pc-mingw32-gcc -U _WIN32 -g -o output.exe -Wall temp.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2)  temp.o
```

#### For Console Applications

To make console application work you must remove **-mwindows** from the gcc command. To do that, you must invoke `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2` and remove the `-mwindows`.

You should obtain something like that afterwards:

```
    i686-pc-mingw32-gcc  -g -o output.exe -Wall temp.c -mms-bitfields -IC:/Mono/include/mono-2.0 -mms-bitfields  -LC:/Mono/lib -lmono-2.0 -lws2_32 -lpsapi -lole32 -lwinmm -loleaut32 -l advapi32 -lversion temp.s
```

#### Anyone can improve mkbundle

**mkbundle is an open sourced C# console application** (**[on mono github](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/mkbundle)**)
so it can be easily modified and recompiled depending on your needs.
Reading the code could also be helpful to understand how it works underneath.
**cmd** usage as the different commands used by mkbundle are hard coded so it would benefit from some parametrization enhancement.