# mkbundle cannot find gtk-sharp assembly on ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, mkbundle

I'm trying to create bundle for my app made with monodevelop on Ubuntu 14. When i execute

```
mkbundle myapp.exe --deps -o myapp
```

error is thrown

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'gtk-sharp'
  at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have found solution for windows here [How to make "mkbundle --deps" option working with mono 3.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226519/how-to-make-mkbundle-deps-option-working-with-mono-3-2-3)
but nothing for ubuntu.

Can someone help with this please?

Comment: Can you installed the GDK SHARP ASSEMPLY in your MACHINE?

Comment: i think u didnot install the assemply or misconfigured...Please read the documentation. And Then Procedd.http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin